# What type of projectile weapons could be built and used under water

Tags: internal-consistency, underwater

What projectile weapons could a civilization of merfolk build without the use of magic.

Comment: Not a duplicate but see also http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30561/low-tech-underwater-weaponry

Comment: Bryan can you narrow this down a bit, the potential options for underwater projectiles are extensive.  If you could provide some limitations or provide a scenario that would help narrow things down.

Comment: Maybe a torpedo?

Comment: @James the projectale weapons must becomposed of stuff built in the sea and must be able to be built underwater.

Comment: @James guns and longbows for example wouldn't work underwater and can't be built underwater.

Comment: @BryanMcClure I understand that but there are still a great many options.  How will one answer be better than any other?  Its not defined.

Comment: Can my merfolk spend some of their time outside of the water?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with most undersea projectiles is that water resistance makes them fairly range-limited - unless, like a torpedo, they have built-in propulsion. Other than that, compressed air or springs can power harpoons (with or without exploding tips) without too much technical know-how. Heck, even an old school crossbow can do the job over a short range.

Comment: can these be built underwater?

Comment: Depends on the level of technology of your mer-folk. Forging a spring, might be tough. Building a hand-pump compressor to compress air or water - easier (heck, its a kids toy! http://www.amazon.com/Water-Powered-Action-Rocket-Classic/dp/B000GKXY5C). A crossbow made of whale-bone and wound sinew - definitely doable.  Heck, items made of rock, bone, and sinew from sea animals was the mainstay of Inuit technology for centuries..

Comment: There is some discussion on it on this archery forum. Might give you some leads to follow up... http://www.archery-forum.com/showthread.php?17666-Underwater-archery

Comment: I suppose the Merfolk have not considered the Shkval underwater rocket yet?

Comment: I'm sure the Merfolk will consider that once they develop solid fuel propulsion systems!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what technology level your merfolk have, but I'd suggest harpoon or spear guns based around compressed air.

Answer (score 0):

They could extract weapons/projectiles from these sea creatures :

1 - Poison projectiles :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laticauda_colubrina

2 - Electrical projectiles :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_fish

3 - Ink projectiles :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squid

4 - Sharp spears :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swordfish